# Web Scraping: How to get the class

Tags: python, html, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to get information of the class when I run the program The output comes up as "None"

```
import requests
import bs4
import lxml

res =requests.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/')

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
link = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/'

div = soup.find('div', {"_1lwNBHmCQJObvqs1fXKSYR" : link}) #This is the class of the New title kinda thing
text = div
print(text)
```

The output I get is

```
None
```

What should I do?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass a `dictionary`, the `key` being the attribute name and the `value` being the value of the attribute. This is how you do it:

```
div = soup.find('div', {"class":"_1lwNBHmCQJObvqs1fXKSYR"}) #Finds the div with class "_1lwNBHmCQJObvqs1fXKSYR"
text = div.text #Identifies text of the div tag
print(text)
```

Output:

```
hot
```

Instead of passing a `dictionary`, you can also pass them as separate parameters like this:

```
div = soup.find('div', class_ = "_1lwNBHmCQJObvqs1fXKSYR") #An "_" is used after class because class is a keyword in python
text = div.text #Identifies text of the div tag
print(text)
```

Output:

```
hot
```

If you want to find the text of all elements with the same class, then use the `find_all` method. This is how you do it:

```
divs = soup.find_all('div', {'class':"_1lwNBHmCQJObvqs1fXKSYR"})

for div in divs:
    print(div.text)
```

Output:

```
hot
new
top
```

Comment: When I try to run ```div = soup.find('div', class_ = "_1lwNBHmCQJObvqs1fXKSYR") #An "_" is used after class because class is a keyword in python
text = div.text #Identifies text of the div tag
print(text)```       It gives me a error saying   ```line 10, in <module>
    text = div.text#Identifies text of the div tag
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' ```

Comment: Is it so? It works alright for me. It would be better if you post your full code.

Comment: ```import requests
import bs4
import lxml

res =requests.get('https://roobet.com/crash')

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')

div = soup.find('div', class_ = "_1lwNBHmCQJObvqs1fXKSYR") #An "_" is used after class because class is a keyword in python
text = div.text#Identifies text of the div tag
print(text)
```

Comment: The code that I provided only works for reddit. Elements in different websites have different classes. All don't have the same class. Just find the class of the element that you want to scrape and provide that class to the class_ parameter. Then it would work.

Comment: Thank you for the help. My bad, I'm kinda new here How do I do that? (Best answer)